# GOLANG Static library linking

Tags: linux, go, static-linking

OS->Ubuntu 16.04 LTS | Go Vesrion-> 1.6.2 64 bit

I am using this github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher PKG

This Pkg need ->libcrypto library

This is the Link of  program what i am compiling from _example folder from above pkg
https://play.golang.org/p/drJGhsWiEi

when i am using-> go build encryption.go (encryption binary genrated)

command-> file ./encryption

encryption: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=91d49d6db997f83dfc722b820e5cab4cc16854cf, not stripped

command-> ldd ./encrption

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffca8fba000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fa93c071000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa93be6d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa93bc4f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa93b886000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055f1aa574000)
```

command-> ./encryption

Output i am getting - {"name":"xeodou", "password": "123456"}

when i am using ->go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' encryption.go

command-> file ./encryption

encryption: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=71fa3d0c30cc5c52dd4f8bea432f8e0468225f9a, not stripped

command-> ldd ./encryption

```
   not a dynamic executable
```

command-> ./encryption

Output i am getting -  Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The thing i am not getting is when same binary run  in other device some it worked some not.

Please guide me

Comment: Do you really want a static binary, or do you want to link a static library to your executable? For the latter you may want to try `-Wl,-Bstatic`. That is different from using `-static`.

Comment: Both will be ok for me ,
I AM getting this errro 
./newencrypto: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Then something went wrong. It linked the shared library, not the static one. Make sure you have the static library installed as well. The linking step can be a bit tricky. The positions of `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` in the linker command actually has an impact whether libraries get statically oder dynamically linked to the application.

Comment: Can you be please frame the command for me 
like  go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' encryption.go

Comment: go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-wl,Bstatic"' encrypto.go
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-wl,Bstatic’

go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-wl,Bdynamic"' encrypto.go
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-wl,Bdynamic’

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by building a static binary? You're still going to need to dynamically link to libpthread at a minimum. Your dependency is using cgo, so there are linking options you probably need to take care of in that package directly.